# How to change the default properties of a css framework as material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm pretty new to css and i'm a little confused here. I'm using material ui with react and redux. I want somehow to edit some properties of a specific component. For example suppose we use TextField with disabled property. As i can see the disabled property contains these properties(i saw that from the material ui node modules in textfield).

```
var styles = {
    root: {
      borderTop: 'none',
      borderLeft: 'none',
      borderRight: 'none',
      borderBottomStyle: 'solid',
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
      borderColor: borderColor,
      bottom: 8,
      boxSizing: 'content-box',
      margin: 0,
      position: 'absolute',
      width: '100%'
    },
    disabled: {
      borderBottomStyle: 'dotted',
      borderBottomWidth: 2,
      borderColor: disabledTextColor
    },
```

But i dont want when it's disable for the borderBottomLine to be dotted. I want to change it to hidden. How to do such an action without affecting the frameworks code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override some default styles of material-ui components. Look at [this](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes) section of docs. Pay attention to this example:

```
import React from 'react';
import {cyan500} from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

// This replaces the textColor value on the palette
// and then update the keys for each component that depends on it.
// More on Colors: http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/colors
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  textField: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
  datePicker: {
    color: 'yellow',
  },
});

// MuiThemeProvider takes the theme as a property and passed it down the hierarchy.
const Main = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
    <AppBar title="My AppBar" />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

export default Main;
```

Here, we override `background-color` for `TextField` component and `color` for `DatePicker`. You should import `getMuiTheme` function, pass to its object with properties which you want to override. Unfortunately, for disabled `TextField` you can override only text color. You can check all properties which you can override from source of default theme - https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/styles/getMuiTheme.js

```
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  textField: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
  datePicker: {
    color: 'yellow',
  },
});
```

After that, you should pass `muiTheme` to the eponymous property
of `MuiThemeProvider` component. This component should wrap root-component of your application.

```
const Main = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
    <AppBar title="My AppBar" />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's sample code. Use `style` in your preferred jsx tag and edit it normally like CSS, but the properties & values must be inside quotation marks("").

```
import React from "react";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";

const index = () => {
  return (
    <AppBar style={{ backgroundColor: "black", height: "65px" }}>
      <Toolbar></Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

export default index;
```